# Right rule for html pagination

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

I have rewrite:

```
RewriteRule (.*\.html$) /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

but some pages have pagination, for example

/test.html?page=2

i need to rewrite it to test-page2.html

i tried

```
RewriteRule (.*)-page([0-9]*)\.html$ /index.php?$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##new rule added by me. This will check if a url has html as well as query string then it will rewrite it to html file.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.html\?(page)=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  %1-%2%3.html [R=301,L]

##OP's previous rule.
##For safer side you could add an additional condition here too.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*\.html)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it doesnt work - i think pagination rewrite must use index.php file as i showed otherwise it will get 404

Comment: @Kaner, could you please do mention here which link you are using? And to which link(to which file) you need to rewrite in backend? From your current question it looked like you want it to rewrite to html file in backend, please confirm once.

Comment: it is frontend - now i have https://test.com/somepage.html?page=3 and i need https://test.com/somepage-page3.html

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes but I think you have already written a rule for backend. Just fix its pattern and the target path.

Comment: @AmitVerma, sure, I have changed it now, let me know if this looks Good to you, cheers.

Comment: @Kaner, Ok please try my edited rules once? Also make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs, let me know.

Comment: first it was 404 - then  i added RewriteBase / and get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error - i get url https://test.com/test-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2-page2.html?page=2

Comment: @Kaner, Could you please do let me know path details like: where htaccess file is present? and where are your html files present? I will get better understanding on question then, thank you.

Comment: .htaccess is in root site directory - i dont have html file - it is rewrite - i have index.php file -  get html file by rewrite RewriteRule (.*\.html$) /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @Kaner, ok try changing `RewriteRule (.*\.html)$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` Rule to `RewriteRule (.*\.html)$  index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` without `/` once and let me know how it goes?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]+)&page=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$  /%1-page%2.html? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-page([0-9]+)\.html$ /index.php?$1&page=$2 [END]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use different browser to test this code.